# How to get which link was clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to get the text `$(el).text()` from a block of multiple links and assign it to HTML input.
I'm using Laravel and Jquery.

My Blade template is a separate component that is generated from some data.

```
<div class="some-class" id="some-id">
    <ol>
        @foreach ($data as $el)
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="some-a-class">{{ $el['name'] }}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ol>
</div>
```

Then I'm looking at how to catch the click of the link, get the text from it, and pass it to the input.

My jQuery code looking like:

```
$('#some-id > a').on('click', function () {
    console.log(this.text());
})
```

From multiple sources found that the way above ^ should be working, but for me, it doesn't even understand that I have clicked.

Maybe is there another way to get the clicked link name?

Thank you.

Comment: try this => `$('#some-id a')` and `console.log($(this).text());` = should work fine. Even if you have multiple `li` with `a` inside.

Comment: Remove the `>`. It's the child selector, yet the `a` is not a child, it's lower level than that

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've tried both ways before asking the question, neither one nor second didn't help.

Comment: ...Okay sure. I think something else is wrong in your code which is not mentioned in the `code` provided here in the question. From what you have mentioned here that should work perfectly.

Comment: Well, I've provided a simple representation of my problem. 
Actually there's an ajax request to the controller which return the view with all data in it, and I can render it successfully to the page via the callback function, but the actual issue is that when I'm trying to get the click of the link, don't get anything!

Comment: @DanPlaton try this => `$(document).on('click', '#some-id a', function () {console.log($(this).text());})`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping that's the one. Thanks

Comment: @DanPlaton Glad to hear that - happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @AlwaysHelping comment was the one I was looking for.

```
$(document).on('click', '#some-id a', function () {console.log($(this).text());})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery selector to this:

```
$('#some-id ol li a')
```

Right now you are trying to select `a` elements that their parent element is `#some-id`, which is not the case. There is a difference between Children of an element (`div > p`) and Descendants of an element (`div p`).